# Logitech HD Webcam C310 to make Video Calls (FaceTime HD Camera not detected)

Tags: facetime, webcam

My FaceTime HD Camera (Built-in) is not detected anymore. Logitech C310 HD Webcam System Requirement does not include MacOS meaning the web camera may not be compatible or work with Macs.

As for Video Calls, it states "You’ll get HD 720p video calling on most major instant messaging applications". I wonder if anyone has used the C310 to overcome a failed Face Time camera issue (in that I can use it to make FaceTime calls with the C310).

Answer (score 1):

The [Logitech HD Webcam C310](https://www.logitech.com/product/hd-webcam-c310) is compatible with OS X Yosemite 10.10 and later as mentioned in the product description on it's website.

An external webcam can be used with FaceTime. Refer to the Apple Support document, [Choose which camera or microphone to use](https://support.apple.com/guide/facetime/choose-which-camera-or-microphone-to-use-fctm26739220/mac) more details.